# R studio server, Can not load package WeibullR. I dont have access to root of server

Tags: installation, shiny, package, shiny-server, weibull

I am trying to install the package WeibullR.  Everything is OK on my personal local machine.  But I am having troubles with installing it to a shiny server.  I do not have access to other than my folder.  I have tried install.packages() and also tried menu method of tools, install packages (using the tar.gz file)  The same thing happens with both.  the installer starts then fails.
Using RStudio Server Pro Version 1.4.1103-4

The output is as follows...

```
install.packages("/apps/rstudio_server_pro/workspace/working/WeibullR_1.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

Installing package into ‘/home/robert_belinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘WeibullR’ ...
** package ‘WeibullR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -m64 -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c LSLR.cpp -o LSLR.o
LSLR.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* LSLR(SEXP)’:
LSLR.cpp:28:2: error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’
  std::unique_ptr<LSLRmodel> LM(new LSLRmodel(arg1));
  ^
LSLR.cpp:28:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  std::unique_ptr<LSLRmodel> LM(new LSLRmodel(arg1));
                           ^
LSLR.cpp:28:51: error: ‘LM’ was not declared in this scope
  std::unique_ptr<LSLRmodel> LM(new LSLRmodel(arg1));
                                                   ^
LSLR.cpp:30:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
make: *** [LSLR.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘WeibullR’
* removing ‘/home/robert_belinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/WeibullR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/apps/rstudio_server_pro/workspace/working/WeibullR_1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
  __ _  ___ ___
```

Has anybody seen this?  Any solutions?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when we try to install WeibullR_1.1 on R version of 3.6.0 due to compatibility issue.
Try to install WeibullR_1.0.12 which will help.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried the newest release of weibullR 1.1.5.  It did not work also.  The 1.0.12 was successful.   For completeness of this thread,  On my PC, R 4.0.2, Rstudio 1.3.959 -no problems.  The problem existed for rstudio server1.4.1103-4 with  R version 3.6.0.